# php only write to database if all records are error free

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

Side Note:  First off, I would like to say that I am not an experienced web developer, so anything in the code I've included that you see can be improved or done better please let me know, as I am always looking to improve and learn from those with more experience and knowledge than myself.

I am creating a form wizard type website, where the user advances through various forms and fills out information.  At the end of the information gathering, I write the collected data to a MySQL database running on WAMP.  The data that I am writing is going to multiple different tables within the database.  There will always be 3 separate INSERT queries, but up to about 15 depending on the data the user inputs ( each query corresponding to a different table).  The problem that I am having is that, if any of the INSERT statements have an error it will not write to that table (good), but it will write to all the other tables (of course).

What I would like to be able to do is only write all the data if none of the queries have errors.  If any of the queries have errors and will not write to their respective table, I would like to not write any data and present an error message to the user.

The only way that I have been able to come up with to accomplish this so far, is to write to the tables using a PDO statement object and on $pdostmt->execute() catch if it returns false.  Then when a failure (false) is encountered, retroactively go back and delete any records that have already been written.  This does not seem to be a good way to go about it, and I'm thinking somewhere out there someone can point me to a better way, but I haven't been able to find that way yet.

Example of 2 INSERT queries below:

```
    $revisionUpdate = "INSERT INTO revision_history (stock_number, revision_date)"
                 ." VALUES ('"
                 .$dataLocation['stocknumber.tpl']['stocknum']."','"    //stock_number
                 .$timestamp  //revision_date
                 ."')";

    $updatestatement = $db_config_data->prepare($revisionUpdate);

    //  Execute the query to update table
    $updatestatement->execute();

    $infoUpdate = "INSERT INTO info (stock_number, revision_date, engineer, customer_name, model,"
                 ."above_one_gigabyte, installed_os, network_location, mac_dupe_check,"
                 ."time_local_tz, time_local_dst, time_offset, time_dst, configurator_version, stephen)"
                 ." VALUES ('"
                 .$dataLocation['stocknumber.tpl']['stocknum']."','"                            //stock_number
                 .$timestamp."','"                                                              //revision_date
                 .$dataLocation['general.tpl']['engineer']."','"                                //engineer
                 .$dataLocation['general.tpl']['company_name']."','"                            //customer_name
                 .$dataLocation['general.tpl']['parent_pn']."',"                                //model
                 .(int)($dataLocation['preflight.tpl']['tot_sys_memory'] == '1gb_greater').",'" //above_one_gigabyte
                 .$dataLocation['preflight.tpl']['installed_os']."','"                          //installed_os
                 .$dataLocation['general.tpl']['network_location']."',"                         //network_location
                 .(int)!array_key_exists('skip_MAC', $dataLocation['pxeactions.tpl']).",'"      //mac_dupe_check
                 .$dataLocation['timezone.tpl']['timezone']."',"                                //time_local_tz
                 .(int)array_key_exists('dst_adjust', $dataLocation['timezone.tpl']).",'"       //time_local_dst
                 .$dataLocation['timezone.tpl']['timezone']."',"                                //time_offset
                 .(int)array_key_exists('dst_adjust', $dataLocation['timezone.tpl']).",'"       //time_dst
                 ."1.0'"                                                                        //configurator_version
                 .")";

    $updatestatement = $db_config_data->prepare($infoUpdate);

    //Example of how I'd catch the failed INSERT query
    if ( !($updatestatement->execute()) )
    {
        print_r($updatestatement->errorInfo());
    }
```

So in the example above if $revisionUpdate succeeded and $infoUpdate failed, I would like to have none of the $revisionUpdate data written to the database, and same goes for any other queries that came before $infoUpdate.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look into transactions, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php. Additionally you should separate your variables from your queries, use placeholders in the query and bind the values.

Comment: Use transactions, if any part fails, rollback the transaction.

Comment: Please learn about prepared statements, that code of yours is an open invitation to SQL injection.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for the link, I think that is exactly what I am looking for.  And thanks for the tip on placeholders as well, I have heard about them but haven't looked too much into them.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @jmoerdyk Thanks for your input! I'm checking that out now and I think it will do exactly what I'd like.

Comment: Here's a link for more information on using the placeholders, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: @Johannes Jander I have heard about SQL injection, but admittedly don't know much about it.  I decided not to learn/implement it here because the project I am doing will be deployed on an intranet at my current company, so I did not expect anyone with malice to be using it.  Having said that, would you still recommend using SQL injection protection?  Is that something that should always be implemented regardless of project, simply because it is better to be safe than sorry even if you don't expect just anyone to use it?

Comment: Placeholders/prepared statements will solve the SQL injection issue. Malice intent isn't the only issue, if a user were to use a single quote your query would break.

Comment: Yes, it is something that should always be implemented regardless of project, simply because **it makes every query run error free**, protecting you from SQL injection only as a side effect. You need them [not for Bobby but for Sarah.](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#whatis)

Comment: Yes, I always use prepared statements so I never have to think about whether this system could be exposed to the internet or not. Prepared statements are not more complicated or more work to write, so there is really no good argument for not using them. And, as others so rightly point out, they also help you avoid strange errors just because a user entered a single quote sign.